# How do different groups of hunter-gatherers decide which group gets to use which land and resources?

Tags: institutions, resource-allocation, commons

I have seen literature about how hunter-gatherer groups allocate common resources *within* groups. But I wonder how "common" resources are allocated *between* groups, i.e. which group gets to use which territory when. Which institutions does it involve?

Comment: resource is a factor of production (see Samuelson's Economics), so land would be a resource, but its 'fruits' would be good not resource. Are you interested in allocation of factors of production or goods between groups? Those are different questions

Comment: I mean resources, i.e. factors of production. In practical terms the territory that groups dwell on live off. I've adjusted the question to reflect that.

Comment: This question is in the domain of anthropology. I believe that it is safe to say that different groups interacted with others varies across geographies, so there probably is no short answer.